# install jre in a non interactive script

Tags: java, bash, jvm

I want to install jre 1.7 in a non interactive script.
is there a way to do that in equivalent of the following?

```
update-alternatives --config java

There are 3 programs which provide 'java'.

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
   1           /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.5.0-gcj/bin/java
*+ 2           /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java
   3           /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7/bin/java
```

Comment: if you know the selection nymber (for example 2) you can type in "echo 2 | sudo alternatives --config java"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have a look at `man update-alternatives`. This reads:

```
   --set name path
          Set  the  program  path  as alternative for name.
          This is equivalent to --config but is non-interactive
          and thus scriptable.
```